# Let G be a finite group and V be the regular CG-Module. Find a submodule of V which is isomorphic to the trivial CG-Module

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

As in the question. I have read through different books and articles and they seem to set W=<$\sum_{g \in G}$ g> as a submodule. I can understand that this is unique, but I fail to see how this is a sub-module of V and how it is isomorphic to the trivial CG-Module.

Answer (score 2):

The action of any $g\in G$ permutes the elements that sum to the generator of your submodule, so $G$ fixes the generator (and hence the submodule it generates). In other words, $G$ acts trivially on this submodule. Also, the submodule is one-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, so it is a copy of the trivial representation of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a submodule as any two elements look like $\alpha= \sum_g z\cdot g \in W$ or $\beta = \sum_g w \cdot g \in W$, with $z, w \in \Bbb C$. Then clearly $\alpha+\beta = \sum_g (z+w)\cdot g \in W$. It isn't too hard to check that $W$ is an abelian group from this. For it to be a submodule, it has to be stable under $G$, and $g' \cdot \alpha = \sum_g g'g z = \sum_g z = \alpha$, since $G$ acts on itself by left translation. Thus, $G$ stabilizes $W$, and in fact fixes $W$, so we say $G$ acts trivially. Since $W$ is visibly one dimensional and carries the trivial action of $G$, it is isomorphic to the trivial $\Bbb C G$ module.

Comment: I thought $W$ was defined to be the $\mathbb{C}[G]$-submodule generated by $\sum_{g\in G}g$. So, it should automatically be a submodule. It happens to be a one-dimensional complex vector space because $G$ fixes the generator.